# Error when creating items AWS Lambda to DynamoDB with python

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, aws-lambda

I am trying to create a new Item in my table and every time I run the following code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from decimal import *
import boto3
import json

def my_handler(event, context):
    marker = event['m']
    latitude = Decimal(event['lat']) 
    longitude = Decimal(event['lon'])
    tableminfo = 'minfo'
    client = boto3.client('dynamodb')

    client.put_item(
      TableName = tableminfo, Item = {
      'marker':{'N' : marker},
      'latitude':{'N' : latitude},
      'longitude':{'N' : longitude},
        }
    )

    success = "Success"     
    return {'success' : success}
```

with the following test parameters in Lambda

```
{
  "m": 1,
  "lat": 52.489505,
  "lon": 13.389687
}
```

I receive an error on the following lines: 
      17,
      "my_handler",
      "'longitude':{'N' : longitude},"

Comment: Do you have any more of the error info returned?  Can you check the logs?  There should be some description of the exact error encountered that would help debug this.

Comment: Actually after you sent this I realized that the logs go much deeper then I realized that Lambda and Dynamo only except strings So I changed my code to add items as strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must update values as string:

```
client.put_item(
      TableName = tableminfo, Item = {
      'marker':{'N' : str(marker)},
      'latitude':{'N' : str(latitude)},
      'longitude':{'N' : str(longitude)},
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the higher-level resource interface that boto3 provides for DynamoDB.  It handles a lot of the low-level details for you.  Here's a version of your code using the resource layer.

Assuming your event looks like this:

```
{
  "m": 1,
  "lat": 52.489505,
  "lon": 13.389687
}
```

This code would persist the data to DynamoDB

```
import boto3

client = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = client.Table('minfo')

def my_handler(event, context):
    item = {
        'marker': event['m'],
        'latitude': event['lat'],
        'longitude': event['lon']}
    table.put_item(Item=item)   
    return {'success' : "Success"}
```

Creating the client and Table at the module level is more efficient because then you won't pay the price of creating them every time your Lambda function is called.